# Include web service on my MVC project (VS2013)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-services, visual-studio-2013

*There is a discussion on stackoverflow explaining this, but not for VS2013.*

I was trying to do it according to the following accepted answer: [Asp.Net MVC and Web Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3958621/asp-net-mvc-and-web-services)

I have no doubts that this answer helps VS2010 and VS2012 users. However, under VS2013, I don't have the web service option when I right click my MVC project and then on "add item".

Should I select WEB API CONTROLLER CLASS V2? I think not... but I keep on waiting to hear from you the best way to include a web service on my MVC project using VS2013.

Comment: Yes, include the Web API controller. Web API is a component, not a project type unto itself: http://www.asp.net/web-api

Comment: @ChrisHardie, I would have no doubts selecting that option if it was called "ASP.NET Web API". Why is it called "ASP.NET Web API Controller"?

Comment: The Web API controller is the endpoint that surfaces data as a web service. Take some time and read the docs, they are very clear and have great examples.

Comment: @ChrisHardie, I did everything like you said and afterwards I created a WebApiConfig.cs similar to RouteConfig.cs where I could configure which url to insert in order to access the webservice. After that I went to Global.asax and did: GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register); but it's still not working. What do I need more to make this webapi controller ready to go?? (I have this other thread about it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22385083/creating-a-webservice-inside-my-mvc-project)